# How to find out charset of text file loaded by input[type="file"] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

I want to read user's file and gave him modified version of this file. I use input with type file to get text file, but how I can get charset of loaded file, because in different cases it can be various... Uploaded file has format .txt or something similar and isn't .html :)

```
var handler = document.getElementById('handler');
var reader = new FileReader();

handler.addEventListener('click', function() {
    reader.readAsText(firstSub.files[0], /* Here I need use a correctly charset */);
});

reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
    console.dir(reader.result.split('\n'));
});
```

Comment: Will the uploaded document be an HTML document? If not, I don't think that you can get this information.

Comment: It isn't HTML document but maybe there are some methods or tricks to easily find out charset @ScottMarcus

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get it.

Comment: Why not just omit the encoding part, just call `reader.readAsText(firstSub.files[0])`. It will assume UTF-8 by default, should work for most text files if preserving the original encoding isn't that important for you.

Comment: The fact of the matter that is very important to preserve the encoding @ChetanJadhavCD

Comment: Add another input to ask, or tell the user what you expect. After all, they are a party in this communication so they shouldn't hold back essential information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out this library [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js)

They also have a working [demo](http://polygonplanet.github.io/encoding.js/tests/detect-file-encoding.html). I would suggest you first try it out with the files that you'll typically work with to see if it detects the encoding correctly and then use the library in your project.

Answer (score 6):

In my case (I made a small web app that accepts subtitle .srt files and removes time codes and line breaks, making a printable text), it was enough to foresee 2 types of encoding: UTF-8 and CP1251 (in all cases I tried – with both Latin and Cyrillic letters – these two types are enough). At first I try encoding with UTF-8, and if it is not successful, some characters are replaced by '�'-signs. So, I check the result for presence of these signs, and, if found, the procedure is repeated with CP1251 encoding. So, here is my code:

```
function onFileInputChange(inputDomElement, utf8 = true) {
    const file = inputDomElement.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, utf8 ? 'UTF-8' : 'CP1251');
    reader.onload = () => {
        const result = reader.result;
        if (utf8 && result.includes('�')) {
            onFileInputChange(inputDomElement, false);
            console.log('The file encoding is not utf-8! Trying CP1251...');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#textarea1').value = file.name.replace(/\.(srt|txt)$/, '').replace(/_+/g, '\ ').toUpperCase() + '\n' + result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions didn't work for what I was trying to do, so I decided to create [my own module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language) that can detect the charset and language of text files.

You load it via the `<script>` tag and then use the `languageEncoding` function to retrieve the charset/encoding:

```html
// index.html

<script src="https://unpkg.com/detect-file-encoding-and-language/umd/language-encoding.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// app.js

languageEncoding(file).then(fileInfo => console.log(fileInfo));
// Possible result: { language: english, encoding: UTF-8, confidence: { language: 0.96, encoding: 1 } }
```

For a more complete example/instructions check out [this part](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language#using-the-script-tag) of the documentation!